# How to use TRIM with QUERY function in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to TRIM the E column in the below query function in Google Sheets. I am not able to find the solution. Can you please help me with this?

=QUERY(E1:K50,"SELECT* ORDER BY K DESC")

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Vineet

Comment: you can nest functions in google sheet

Comment: do you mean to trim the result of the query?

Comment: replace(source_string, " ", "", 0), and the same for the nth-1  leter

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({TRIM(E1:E50), F1:K50}, "order by Col7 desc", ))
```